# Retrieve all items on page with Python scraper

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm very new to this, but I've managed to build a scraper.

The only problem is I only get the last item of the page as result.

The page has 25 results. How I can get all the items on the page?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
from lxml import html 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv

r = requests.get("http://www.mediamarkt.be/mcs/productlist/_128-tot-150-cm-51-tot-59-,98952,501091.html?langId=-17")

soup = BeautifulSoup((r.content),'lxml')

links = soup.find_all("h2")

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "price small"})

for item in g_data:
    prijs=item.text.encode("utf-8")

for link in links:
    if "TV" in link.text:
        product=link.text.encode("utf-8").strip()

print prijs
print product
```

Comment: The following are list comprehensions that would retrieve all results in lists, instead of one result in a single variable `prijs = [item.text.encode("utf-8") for item in g_data]` and `product = [link.text.encode("utf-8").strip() for link in links if "TV" in link.text]`

Answer (score 1):

You're finding the product, and every time you do, you're overwriting it with the next product.  It's this line here:

```
product=link.text.encode("utf-8").strip()
```

product gets overwritten each time through the loop until it's done, and you're left with the last one from the page.  You either want to append each result to the previous with something like this...

```
product = ""
for link in links:
    if "TV" in link.text:
        product+=link.text.encode("utf-8").strip() + " "
```

Or store the results in a list.